# Count Results from a Select in a Join

Tags: php, mysql, select, join, count

I have this query that works as I need. However I would like to have a column showing number of times a record repeats.

The query:

```
SELECT total.Total, subqry.Company AS Supplier, company.Company AS Customer, purchase_details.CompanyID, 
                            product.Description1, purchase_details.PurchaseID, purchase_details.PurchaseCreated, 
                            purchase_details.Completed, purchase_details.OriginalOrd
                    FROM purchase_details
                        LEFT JOIN product ON purchase_details.PartNumber = product.PartNumber
                        LEFT JOIN orders ON purchase_details.OriginalOrd = orders.OrderID
                        LEFT JOIN contact ON orders.ContactLinkID = contact.ID
                        LEFT JOIN company ON contact.LinkID = company.LinkID
                        LEFT JOIN (SELECT company.Company, purchase_details.CompanyID FROM company 
                                    LEFT JOIN purchase_details ON company.ID = purchase_details.CompanyID) 
                                    AS subqry ON purchase_details.CompanyID = subqry.CompanyID
                        LEFT JOIN (SELECT OriginalOrd, count(DISTINCT CompanyID) AS Total FROM purchase_details
                                    GROUP BY OriginalOrd) AS total ON purchase_details.OriginalOrd = total.OriginalOrd
                    WHERE purchase_details.Completed = $show AND
                        (subqry.Company LIKE :search
                        OR company.Company LIKE :search
                        OR product.Description1 LIKE :search
                        OR purchase_details.PartNumber LIKE :search
                        OR purchase_details.PurchaseID LIKE :search
                        OR purchase_details.OriginalOrd LIKE :search)
                    GROUP BY PurchaseID
```

The company id column returns:

```
504
1739
504
1389
504
```

I would like to return the info below so ideally in a join:

```
504    |   3
1739   |   1
504    |   3
1389   |   1
504    |   3
```

I will use this column in the php application to trigger other functions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would recommend you to count this on php directly. Changing your query to do what you want seems much more complicated given so many  left joins.

Comment: Hi Jorge thanks for your reply. I am using a while loop to display the results in a table. How would you achieve your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add company_id to the GROUp BY list after PurchaseID and add another column count(DISTINCT company_id) company_count to the select.

```
SELECT
....//other columns
count(DISTINCT purchase_details.CompanyID) company_count
FROM
...//rest of queries
GROUP BY purchase_details.CompanyID,PurchaseID
;
```

Comment: I have tried this, it returns 504   |   1, 1739 | 1, 504  | 1 etc

Comment: well PurchaseID might have created the issue, does one PurchaseID belong to other CompanyID? If not exchange the order of GROUP BY columns

Comment: yes, in this table the CompanyID and PurchaseID are used more than once. The application creates a purchase orders table where there might be a number of orders for one supplier and a number of suppliers in more than one order.

Comment: Ok,does GROUPing BY PurchaseID matters to you or just the CompanyID is sufficient, cause this is the case I think the result is correct then...

Comment: Yes group by PurchaseId is important as the user only needs to see the whole order not all the items in the order

Comment: ok, then what would have happened is, 504 may also belong to more than one company and incase we are good I guess.
else
can you start a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/ here so that we can try there(no need to create every table imp tables will go the task)

Comment: I'm using company data so I will need to stripe that out for Privacy reasons. Leave it with me

Comment: well I am not saying expose your company data, you can raise the same scenario though.

Comment: Hi Avisheks http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb5f8/2/0 took me a while to sort out fiddle but i'm there now

Comment: do you not want your output something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/542d3/11/0

Comment: yes but i also need to see each purchase order. 504 = 3 therefore it should be seen three times, but it is close.

Comment: It is the group by at the end causing the problem

Comment: The best way to get PurchaseID for one CompanyID is with GROUP_CONCAT clause. Something like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/542d3/32

Else I think, this is how you want ur O/P to look like:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/542d3/31

Comment: Hi Avisheks, thanks for you time and help, it has been much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use group by company_id

```
select count(company_id) as c
from table_name
group by company_id;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you quick reply. How did you plan to include this, a separate query, sub query or in a join?

Comment: If you wanna implement in that query you cant have repeated values in that column . Instead of group by purchase_id use the column name which you wanna count.

Answer (score 0):

This bit looks odd...

```
   SELECT c.Company
        , pd.CompanyID 
     FROM company c
     LEFT 
     JOIN purchase_details pd
       ON c.ID = pd.CompanyID
```

You're selecting no information from purchase_details that's not already present in company. So why bother?

Also, what might ":search" actually look like?

Comment: The join you picked up on gets the company name from the company table where as the companyid is in the original order(working on someone else table structure). Search is a string from the search field in the application

Comment: 1. The `companyid` is in the `company` table (`id`). We know this because you're joining `pd.companyid` on `c.id`! 2. So search is always wrapped in '%' wildcards?

Comment: Yes search is wrapped in %%. We have contacts that are both supplier and customer. The purchase_details table has the OriginalOrd in it, In the orders table we have ContactID and in the contacts table CompanyID and in the company table the company.Name

Comment: 2. OK - got it. 1. No, you're missing my point (or maybe I'm missing yours). You're OUTER JOINing on a table from which you select no additional information - we already know the ids of the companies. If you want to the ids of the companies that placed orders, then that would (appear to) be an INNER JOIN !?!

Comment: I'm pretty new to this, so yes I'm probably missing your point. However I think I see what you are getting at. The left join that ends in subqry is purely because I'm pulling the same type of info for two different uses, one to get the supplier name and the other to get the customer both, both are stored in the contacts table. if you don't create the subqry it doesn't work